# MATLAB-style terminal output in Python

Tags: python, matlab

I wasn't able to find this question in a few searches. Consider the following MATLAB struct:

```
>> s = struct('field_a', 1:10, 'field_b', 1:1000);
>> disp(s)
s =
    field_a: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
    field_b: [1x1000 double]
```

In a python dictionary (ignore the +1 differences), it might be:

```
>>> d = {'field_a': np.arange(10), 'field_b': np.arange(1000)}
>>> print(d)
    <<floods terminal with output>>
```

Is it possible to get python to print out something like:

```
>>> print(d)
{'field_b': array([1, 2, ..., 998, 999]), 'field_a': array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])}
```

I wouldn't necessarily want this to be limited to numpy data types but any multi-item element that can get unwieldy. And obviously, I would like to be able to inspect all values if needed, at any time.

Comment: Not sure whether you should want to overload `print`, but I suppose one could create `myprint` and easily catch some situations where you want to deviate from how print behaves (and otherwise just call print).

Comment: [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) might be able to do something similar, and of course using a MATLAB-like environment such as `ipython` might be more to your taste than the simple python interactive shell.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. All you need to do is to subclass the `dict` class and provide your custom implementation of the `__str__()` method.